# Is an inexpensive used Pentax lens worth buying for mounting on a Canon Rebel T5i?

Tags: canon, zoom, lens-adapter, pentax

I have found an smc Pentax-A 25-135mm f/4 at a local thrift, for $60. Everything seems to be working great, and it's without scratches. Is this a great deal, or not so much? Is this a good lens?

I have a Canon Rebel T5i. I'm an amateur photographer, but I'm hoping to make something of myself with photography. Can I adapt this lens to my camera, and if so, what adapter is needed?

Comment: "Is an inexpensive used Pentax lens worth buying for mounting on a Canon Rebel T5i? ... Is this a great deal, or not so much? " That highly depends upon exactly what kind of shooting you wish to do with such a setup. Manual aperture, manual focus, and stopped down metering aren't much of a drag for some types of photography. For other applications they would be near debilitating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Pentax A 25-135mm f/4, but there is a Pentax A **28**-135mm f/4.

Pentax lenses will **not** mount directly onto a Canon EOS body (like your DSLR).  You can get cheap adapters from e-Bay. but I do not recommend this.

That lens is all manual and even if it was not, when used on a Canon via an adapter it would only work manually (that's manual focus, manual aperture).

What you need is lenses that are compatible with the Canon EF and EF-S mounts, which, for your purposes, will allow all automated functions the lenses support.  Sigma and Tamron also make lenses which are compatible with Canon EF/EF-S but be careful because they also make the same lenses for Nikon and other DSLRs, which will not be compatible with your Canon.

The world of lens-body adapters is full of pitfalls and devil-in-the-detail issues for the unwary, so I really do not recommend it until you have a lot more knowledge under your belt.

However, if you particularly want to pursue this the kind of adapter you would need is [something like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Pixco-Camera-AF-Confirm-Adapter-For-Pentax-PK-to-Canon-5D-II-T3i-7D-60D-T2i-T1i-/401363633362?hash=item5d732304d2:g:dxEAAOSwWdZZZHdU).

Please note that this is **not** a product recommendation, but to show you the kind of think you need.  Not all adapters will, for example, allow focus confirmation to work, while this type *claims* to.

I am assuming you have a kit lens (an 18-55) for your Canon.  Those are actually pretty good lenses and if you want to invest in a lens as a "next step" I'd suggest a **used** Canon 50mm f1.8 would be the best choice.  That will get you into wide aperture shooting and fixed focal length primes.  They're typically used for e.g. head-and-shoulder portraits with strong background blurring (but this isn't their only purpose).

There's a similar budget option called the [Yongnuo YN 50mm f1.8](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1111454-REG/yongnuo_yn50mm_50mm_ef_for_1_8.html) for about the $50.  There's [an informal review of it here](https://petapixel.com/2014/12/25/first-review-40-yongnuo-50mm-f1-8-nifty-fifty-clone/) for those who are interested.  They certainly are not a well known name in lenses (they're well known for cheap flashes, however).

Again I cannot (site rules) recommend any specific product, but this is the kind of thing to consider.

Comment: The advice to purchase a 50mm lens is irrelevant to the content of the question.